# Get mean of rows matching a criteria grouped by name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` like below, I want to get a new column grouped by name where it matches criteria Repeat = "Yes" & Allowed = "Yes" and show all the names including which has no matches.

- Code for input `dataframe`

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A"),
                 Repeat = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"),
                 Allowed = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"))
df1
#>    Name Repeat Allowed
#> 1     A    Yes     Yes
#> 2     B    Yes     Yes
#> 3     C     No     Yes
#> 4     A    Yes     Yes
#> 5     B    Yes     Yes
#> 6     B    Yes     Yes
#> 7     C     No     Yes
#> 8     C     No     Yes
#> 9     A    Yes      No
#> 10    A    Yes      No
```

- Code showing the desired output `dataframe`

```r
df_results <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C"),
                            Calculation = c(0.5, 1, 0))
df_results
#>   Name Calculation
#> 1    A         0.5
#> 2    B         1.0
#> 3    C         0.0
```

I tried searching many examples but couldn't find one relevant to mine. I have tried using Summarise, but it gives me incorrect values and on using aggregate function, the error comes up as arguments must have same length.

```r
df %>%  group_by(Name) %>% filter(Repeat == "Yes" & Allowed == "Yes" ) %>%
  dplyr::summarise("Calculation" = n()/length(df$Name))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your request. That said, I suggest a possible solution (see reprex below) with the `data.table` package to get the result table you defined.

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, .(matches = mean(fifelse(Repeat == "Yes" & Allowed == "Yes", 1, 0))), by = .(Name)][]
#>    Name matches
#> 1:    A     0.5
#> 2:    B     1.0
#> 3:    C     0.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hello @vpk25. Welcome to SO! Please consider marking this answer as accepted if it correctly answers your request. If not, please specify what is wrong. Cheers